# verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: android, ssl, openssl, certificate

I am using the openssl client command to connect with the verisign server. I am using the following command.

> openssl s_client  -connect 69.58.181.89:443

Is gives the following error.

> verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate

After modifying the command to the following, I can avoid this error on my laptop (Mac OS), but not on my Android device. (the missing certificate was included in to the ca-bundle.crt file)

> openssl s_client -CAfile ca-bundle.crt -connect 69.58.181.89:443

What can be the issue for the openssl client, not to pick the certificate from the crt file?

Can someone please give an idea to solve this?

Comment: Do you use the same command with the same bundle on Android and OS X and do you get the same certificate back?

Comment: Yes I use the same command with the same certificate bundle. I get the same certificates too. However the verification codes are different - Verify return code: 0 (ok) (OS X) & Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate) (Android)

Comment: Could you please check on either some Linux/Windows system or with an OpenSSL version which is not done by Apple? They've patched OpenSSL so that it checks against the system keystore if the CA can not be found in the given CA store, see https://hynek.me/articles/apple-openssl-verification-surprises/

Comment: I just checked on a Linux machine. Without the certificate bundle the verification code is 20 & with the CA bundle it is 0. The results are as same as on the OS X. It seems on Android the CA bundle is not used when looking for the certificates